# how to redirect url query stringstart with =h

Tags: redirect

I installed a plugin in a wordpress site, that generate many address with siteurl/?h=xxxxxx&cid=xxx
(example:https://www.site.ext/?h=54389be&cid=148)
how can I redirect all adresses start with ?h= to my home page?

I add some rule to rankmath, but it not work